Running the server for SQL Workbench without starting it manually in the terminal
I had some big troubles getting My SQL Workbench to run on my macbook. Thanks to some posts here I can now manage to log in and have everything activated. The remaining problem is simply this:
I start SQL workbench, click on the default connection with localhost 3306. I get to the start menu, but the server is always down initially. Only after I manually enter sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start in the terminal, the server starts to work.
Is it possible to set a default such that the server starts running automatically when I log in to SQL workbench? Or is that how it supposed to work?
I am completely new to SQL and databases, thus I appreciate any help.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/macos-installation-launchd.html Search here about auto-start
